# How to publish a package that includes scripts and/or executables?

Tags: texlive, package-writing, ctan, python

I'm preparing to publish my first package, and am not sure about the best way to proceed.  I understand the standard CTAN publishing approach, but I'm dealing with a somewhat atypical case since my package involves Python scripts and (for Windows) batch files.  I'm not sure what special treatment these may require.

## Background

My package allows Python code to be typeset within a document and/or saved to an external file from which it is executed (and then the output can be pulled back into LaTeX).  Basically, a combination of most features of `python.sty`, `SageTeX`, and `minted`, with a lot of emphasis on speed (everything is hashed, only run when changed, and run in parallel) and usability (all Python errors can be reported in the LaTeX editor, with correct line numbers).

Getting this to work involves running `latex file.tex`, `pythontex.bat file` (or `pythontex.py file`, depending on operating system; the `.bat` basically just calls the `.py`), and then `latex file.tex`.  The problem is that the package needs to be installed such that `pythontex.bat` (or `pythontex.py`) can be run without specifying the full path (that is, be somewhere that is in the system path).  They need to behave as if they were binaries in TeX Live's `bin/` folder.  This is necessary so that they can easily be invoked by a LaTeX editor or from the command line.

There is one additional complication. The package requires two additional Python files, `pythontex_utils.py` and `pythontex_types.py`.  These need to be able to be imported by any Python script.  That means that either they need to be installed as a Python package (so Python can automatically find them), or I need a way to automatically determine the full path to their location (so they can be imported using the path).

## Possible approaches

- `SageTeX` bundles all the Sage/Python stuff within Sage.  It is up to the user to make the `.sty` file accessible.  I could take a similar approach:  put my code in a Python package, and hopefully come up with some kind of automatic installer for the `.sty` file.  That would make it easier to deal with the Python side of things (version 2.x versus 3.x, etc.), but would also mean that the package isn't on CTAN.
- I could put everything on CTAN except for the Python stuff that must be importable, and publish that separately as a Python package. The main disadvantage would be that users would have to install two things.
- I could put everything on CTAN, if there are satisfactory ways of dealing with all of my questions.  That approach is preferable.

## Summary

- I would like a way to install a `.py` or `.bat` file as part of a package installation, so that it can be launched just as if it were an executable in TeX Live's `bin/` folder (since that folder is added to the system path).
- This may be a restatement of the first point, but any elucidation of how TeX Live handles scripts would be very useful.  For example, `sty2dtx` is a Perl script, but at least in the Windows installation of TeX Live, there is also a `sty2dtx.exe` under `bin/`, which launches the Perl script.  It would be nice to know if these binaries are coming from package authors or TeX Live.  I suspect TeX Live (at least for `sty2dtx`, there is no `.exe` on CTAN).
- Unless I also publish a separate Python package, I need a way to get the full path to where a LaTeX package is installed, based just on knowing the package name, so my programs can find the Python files that must be imported.

Comment: For inspiration you might want to have a look at `SympyTeX`: http://elec.otago.ac.nz/w/index.php/SympyTeX, which integrates sympy and LaTeX but can also be used for plain python.

Comment: Have you published this yet? I am very interested in using it in my thesis work. Sagetex now uses forever to compile my document!

Comment: @obtitus After some delays and feature creep, a beta version of my PythonTeX code is now available at [GitHub](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based on the functionality of your package it seems to me that it belongs more to TeX than Python realm, so I agree with you that CTAN is the best place to put it.  There are several different aspects in your question, I will try to address them below as thoroughly and generally as I can.

### Scripts vs. binaries

Firstly, the good news for you is that scripts are much easier to integrate into TeX distributions than compiled programs.  To get the latter into TeX Live or MiKTeX it is best to get in touch with the distribution maintainer(s) through the appropriate mailing list.

### Submission to CTAN

You need to decide whether to submit your package to CTAN as a flat `.zip` archive or in a `.tds.zip` [TDS](http://tug.org/tds/tds.html) format (see also [TDS submission guidelines](http://dante.ctan.org/tds-guidelines.html)).  TDS avoids ambiguity in file layout, but be sure to adhere to the specification - a flat `.zip` with no subdirectories is preferred over messed up `.tds.zip`.  **Test your `.tds.zip` before submitting**, e.g., install into TEXMFHOME and see if everything works (see below on how to test the executable scripts).  Here's the layout I would suggest for your package `pythontex`:

```
doc/
   +-- latex/ 
            +-- pythontex/
                         +-- pythontex.pdf
                         +-- README
scripts/
       +-- pythontex/
                    +-- pythontex.bat
                    +-- pythontex.py
                    +-- pythontex_types.py
                    +-- pythontex_utils.py
source/
      +-- latex/ 
               +-- pythontex/
                            +-- pythontex.dtx
tex/
   +-- latex/ 
            +-- pythontex/
                         +-- pythontex.sty
```

You should include all package files in the archive, not just the source files (e.g., not only `.dtx`, but also the `.sty` file derived from it).  You should also include a short and clear `README` file specifying the purpose of the package, its license (needs to be free to include in TL), its contents (files and their purpose) and any other requirements needed to install and use the package (e.g., external dependencies like Python).

### Executable scripts

Directories with executables (i.e., those added to `PATH`) are not included in TDS specification, but as a package author you don't need to worry about that.  Just put your scripts under `scripts/<package name>` and make clear in the package `README`, which script is the main program to be executed.  TeX distros will then add a symlink (TL on Unix) or a launching wrapper (win32, TL and MiKTeX) in the `bin` directory.

Whether to include a wrapper for launching the script is up to you.  In principle, this is not needed nowadays for TeX Live and MiKTeX - both have their own, specialized wrappers for this purpose. However, some users may need to install your package directly from CTAN (e.g., to use with older TL version), so adding at least a `.bat` wrapper for Windows (see example below) may be nice.  For Unix just start your main script with `#!/usr/bin/env python` (for system portability `/usr/bin/env` is recommended over hardcoding interpreter's absolute path).

For windows I can suggest the following wrapper (if saved as `pythontex.bat` it will execute `pythontex.py` script).

```py
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
rem assuming the main script is in the same directory
if not exist "%~dpn0.py" (
  echo %~nx0: main script "%~dpn0.py" not found>&2
  exit /b 1
)
rem check if interpreter is on the PATH
for %%I in (python.exe) do set "PYTHONEXE=%%~$PATH:I"
if not defined PYTHONEXE (
  echo %~nx0: Python interpreter not installed or not on the PATH>&2
  exit /b 1
)
"%PYTHONEXE%" "%~dpn0.py" %*
```

As I mentioned, TeX Live and MiKTeX use their own methods of launching scripts, though I'm only familiar with TL's side of things.  TeX Live uses `runscript.tlu` utility for this and users can make use of it also for their own custom or manually installed scripts.  This can be also used by package authors for testing, e.g., you could test if your `.tds.zip` works correctly.  For details see the output of `runscript -h` (add `-v` switch to learn all the gory details of the actual implementation).  Here's an excerpt from it:

```
The following script types and their file extensions are currently
supported and searched in that order:

  Lua      (.tlu;.texlua;.lua) --  included
  Perl     (.pl)               --  included
  Ruby     (.rb)               --  requires installation
  Python   (.py)               --  requires installation
  Tcl      (.tcl)              --  requires installation
  Java     (.jar)              --  requires installation
  VBScript (.vbs)              --  part of Windows
  JScript  (.js)               --  part of Windows
  Batch    (.bat;.cmd)         --  part of Windows

Finally, Unix-style extensionless scripts are searched as last and
the interpreter program is established based on the she-bang (#!)
specification on the very first line of the script.  This can be
an arbitrary program but it must be present on the search path.
```

It is recommended to write new utilities in Lua, if only possible, since Lua interpreter is now available out of the box on all platforms thanks to LuaTeX.  A close second is Perl, which is shipped with TL on win32.  Anything else has to be installed separately on Windows.

### Finding script/package resources

Complex scripts might be spread over multiple files and there is no silver bullet solution to how to locate such files.  The standard way of finding files in TeX Live (which now works in MiKTeX too) is to use Kpathsea and its `kpsewhich` utility, e.g., `kpsewhich -format texmfscripts pythontex_utils.py` will output the full path to `pythontex_utils.py` if it finds it in `scripts` subdirectory under one of the TEXMF trees.  In LuaTeX, Kpathsea library is built-in and can be accessed directly.  There might be some other, perhaps better ways, which are specific to Python, Perl, etc., but this should be asked elsewhere.

Comment: just to reinforce the statement -- a flat .zip is preferred over messed up .tds.zip (and messing up is, sadly, easy to do).  regarding inclusion in tex live, once a package is posted to ctan, if it has an acceptable free license (e.g. lppl for the tex files) it will automatically be considered for tex live.  but if you want to clarify your intent, mention that when you submit the zip file to ctan.

Comment: @barbarabeeton However, once you get your `.tds.zip` build-script right, things usually work nicely. (I have quite a few nowadays, including the LaTeX3 ones!)

Comment: to reinforce barbara: a flat .zip is the sine qua non; if you make a .tds.zip, fine, but ctan will ignore it if there's any problem with its format, content or layout (the content of the flat .zip is considered authoritative).

Comment: @JosephWright -- you have experience with this.  the original question involves the poster's "first package", and it's a complicated one.  what *might* be done is to ask the ctan maintainers for help in creating a build script, or to send back the one that is created to build tex live, so updates could be generated more readily.

Comment: Very thorough response.  That clarifies a lot.  Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the `script` directory be organized as `script->latex->python->pythontex`? At least, that is the organization that ConTeXt uses for scripts.

Comment: @Aditya: there is no standardisation in that respect, AFAIK, and kpathsea doesn't make any use of how subdirectories are organised under <TEXMF>/scripts. The most common approach seems to follow <TEXMF>/scripts/<PACKAGE_NAME> convention that I suggested.

Comment: `<TEXMF>/scripts/<PACKAGE_NAME>` may clash if both LaTeX and ConTeXt have packages/modules with the same name. That is why, I think it is better to add a `latex` or `context` subdirectory, just as is done for all other sub-trees (`tex/`, `doc/`, etc.). At least, all ConTeXt packages follow this strategy.

Comment: @aditya: all the context contributed packages that we (ctan) mirror are in tds format.  one day i'll sort that out (with a parallel flattened tree, or something), but we can't do anything about the structure of things we mirror *in the mirror process*

Answer (score 20):

1. Regarding flat `.zip` vs. `.tds.zip`, CTAN now rejects uploads that consist only of a TDS-structure, whether as a `.zip` or not.  They now require creating a "browsing-friendly" relatively flat structure for the main tree.
2. Regarding creation of `.tds.zip`, I would strongly discourage doing it here.  And in general, unless there is a *specific reason* to do so.  Usually there isn't.  But that is really OT from the original question.
3. Regarding scripts finding their modules, I just wrote a rather lengthy reply to another person (Michael Palmer) on this topic.  See the thread starting at http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2012-September/032417.html.

If you want to discuss further, feel free to write me or the tex-live list.  (As for MiKTeX, I have no idea.)

Best,
Karl (karl@freefriends.org)

Answer (score 3):

This is answering your last question on how to get the location of the scripts. The solution relies on either the ConTeXt wrapper script `mtxrun` or the ConTeXt Lua library `resolvers`.

I am the author of the  [`t-vim`](http://modules.contextgarden.net/vim) module in ConTeXt, which uses the vim editor for syntax highlighting code (similar to the `pygments` package in LaTeX). As part of this module, I distribute a `2context.vim` vim script, which does the actual conversion. I include the script in the same directory as the regular `.tex` file (I initially (~2008/9) had used the `script` subdirectory, but kpathsea could not search it; I never checked again to see if the situation has changed), and let kpathsea figure out the location of the file.

Roughly speaking, in MkII (`pdftex` backend), the call to vim is:

```
mtxrun --direct -c vim "source kpse:2context.vim" <other options>
```

The ConTeXt wrapper script `mtxrun` expands `kpse:...` to the full path returned by `kpsewhich`. This would also work with LaTeX, but you will introduce a dependency on `context`.

In MkIV (`luatex` backed), I use the ConTeXt `kpse` library to get the location of the file at the TeX end:

```
  \ctxlua{context.setvalue("vimtyping@script_name",resolvers.resolve("full:2context.vim"))}
```

where `resolvers.resolve("full:...")` returns the full path of a file. Then I call vim using:

```
  vim -c "source \vimtyping@script_name" <other options>
```

Using this approach, the script can be included in any directory where kpathsea can find it, and the user does not have to install it separately.